# Get Local Ip using REMOTE_ADDR

Tags: c#, ip

I'm trying to get local ip address using this code in my website:

```
string ip  = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

The scenario is I try to call the website from 2 different ip address, the first call has been successfully but the second one is still displaying the first ip address.

But if I open the web using CTRL+SHIFT+R then both ip address were correct.

Somehow, the string ip  = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]; is not refreshing and carried out the cache from previous call.

How do I get around this?

Below are several codes to get local ip address but it didn't work, it can only get the server ip (IIS IP) not the local ip

```
//code no 1
        public static string GetLocalIPAddress()
    {
        var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                return ip.ToString();
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("No network adapters with an IPv4 address in the system!");
    }


//code no : 2
        public static string[] GetAllLocalIPv4(NetworkInterfaceType _type)
    {
        List<string> ipAddrList = new List<string>();
        foreach (NetworkInterface item in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            if (item.NetworkInterfaceType == _type && item.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
            {
                foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation ip in item.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
                {
                    if (ip.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                    {
                        ipAddrList.Add(ip.Address.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return ipAddrList.ToArray();
    }

//code no 3

    public string GetLocalIpAddress2()
    {
        UnicastIPAddressInformation mostSuitableIp = null;

        var networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

        foreach (var network in networkInterfaces)
        {
            if (network.OperationalStatus != OperationalStatus.Up)
                continue;

            var properties = network.GetIPProperties();

            if (properties.GatewayAddresses.Count == 0)
                continue;

            foreach (var address in properties.UnicastAddresses)
            {
                if (address.Address.AddressFamily != AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                    continue;

                if (IPAddress.IsLoopback(address.Address))
                    continue;

                if (!address.IsDnsEligible)
                {
                    if (mostSuitableIp == null)
                        mostSuitableIp = address;
                    continue;
                }

                // The best IP is the IP got from DHCP server
                if (address.PrefixOrigin != PrefixOrigin.Dhcp)
                {
                    if (mostSuitableIp == null || !mostSuitableIp.IsDnsEligible)
                        mostSuitableIp = address;
                    continue;
                }

                return address.Address.ToString();
            }
        }

        return mostSuitableIp != null
            ? mostSuitableIp.Address.ToString()
            : "";
    }

//code no 4
        public  string GetIP4Address()
        {
            string IP4Address = String.Empty;

            foreach (IPAddress IPA in Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()))
            {
                if (IPA.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    IP4Address = IPA.ToString();
                    break;
                }
            }


            return IP4Address;
        }
```

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: I can't pinpoint exactly what's happening for you, but generally I would avoid `HttpContext.Current` as its a deprecated practice. Access the request through your controller.

Comment: I've updated the thread, the reason I'm usng the httpcontext is because none of the other codes seem able to get my local ip, it can only get my iis ip address